# Creating a simple packet router in C++, how to keep track of 'clients'?

Tags: c++, algorithm, networking

I need a class `Router` that receives IP packets, parses them and sends to clients (from class `Client`). Of course each `Client` must tell `Router` they want to receive packets for an specific port.

```
template <class T>
class Router
{
public:
    //Packets arrive from the world to a Client
    virtual bool onReceivePacket(Packet<T>::Ptr packet);
    //Packets arrive from a Client to the world
    virtual void onSendPacket(Packet<T>::Ptr packet);
protected:
    std::unordered_map<int, std::shared_ptr<Client>> tcpRoutingTable;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::shared_ptr<Client>> udpRoutingTable;
}
```

The interface for `Router` is pretty simple. Somebody will call `onReceivePacket` with a packet from the world and `Router` will extract the destination port of the packet and if it's TCP or UDP it'll simply route to the Client accordingly by calling `onReceive` on the client. Example:

```
auto client = tcpRoutingTable.at(packet->tcpDestination());
client->onReceive(packet);
```

However there are two things bothering me:

1) How to keep a relation between `Router` and `Client`? If I simply make a `Client` and subscribe it to the `Router`, then the `Router` also has to include a pointer to itself inside `Client`. This relation is very fragile as if the `Client` or `Router` go away it'll end in undefined behaviour. Also, by simply using `shared_ptr` on both `Client` and `Router` we get the problem of recursion of `shared_ptr`s that include each other and therefore never go away.

2) Is an `unordered_map` the best way to route packets? I see no fastest way than simply checking for an integer and sending to the specific client. However the answer for the first question migth change this model.

As you can see, `Router` is single threaded, because the thing that calls `Router` with packets from the world is also single threaded. But can I benefit from multiple threads?

Comment: "*If I simply make a `Client` and subscribe it to the `Router`, then the `Router` also has to include a pointer to itself inside `Client`*" - It is the `Client`'s responsibility to keep track of which `Router`s it has registered with. That way it can register with multiple `Router`s if it wants to. Just as it is `Router`'s responsibility to keep track of which `Client`s have registered with it. If you want to, then yes, `Router` can automatically add itself to any `Client` that registers with it.

Comment: "*This relation is very fragile as if the `Client` or `Router` go away it'll end in undefined behaviour.*" - no, it won't. Just make sure that if the `Client` goes away first that it unregisters itself from all `Router`s it is actively registered with. And if the `Router` goes away first, make sure it notifies all `Client`s that are registered with it so they can unregister themselves, or at least make the `Router` remove itself from them.

Comment: Simple routing does _not_ maintain state of the end-devices. That was the entire purpose of IP. Also a pure router knows nothing about the upper-layer protocols. _Some_ transport protocols (TCP, UDP) use port numbers, but a router has no idea about that, and other transport protocols use something else or nothing at all for addressing. Routers simply route each packet independently, using the destination IP address, regardless of what came before. Routers do not know or care about any of the end-devices (they do not have clients, the client/server model is an application-layer concept).

Comment: @RonMaupin you're rigth. I think my class name choice is bad. What I intended to do was a class where people could register their Clients to receive things on each port. But, don't a home router routes based on TCP/UDP source port? If a packet is sent from my home to the world the router associates the source port of the packet to the computer which sent it so he can give back the answer, isn't it?

Comment: "_But, don't a home router routes based on TCP/UDP source port?_" No, not really. Routing happens by destination IP address. What you mean is NAPT, where the network (IP) and transport (TCP, UDP) addresses are translated to other addresses. That really has nothing to do with routing, and it is very complex, requiring translation tables for each protocol. Your original premise of a simple router does not fit with that. Also, the end-device do not register with the router; each packet is handled on its own merit.

Comment: A router or firewall at the edge of a network is a convenient place do do NAPT, which is only required (or even wanted) where you need to send Private addressing on the public Internet, or you have overlapping network addressing. Actual routing does not use NAPT, and you could have many other routers internal to a network that only route, not NAPT. NAPT is a kludge designed to extend the life of IPv4 addressing until IPv6 can become ubiquitous, and it breaks protocols other than TCP, UDP, and ICMP, even some applications and protocols that use TCP or UDP.

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks, now I understand better. Just to clarify, I need to do this because I'm using OpenVPN3 as a library, and at that level it does not use the system, therefore I need to craft and parse IP packets by hand and therefore do my own "NAPT"

Comment: OK, but NAPT is going to be far from simple. You will need a translation table for each transport protocol (TCP, UDP, and ICMP). TCP and UDP use the same port numbers, but they are not the same ports, and ICMP has query IDs, and they must all be translated in a table for the protocol. Then, besides changing the IP address and the IPv4 header checksum, you will need to change the checksum for the transport protocols using the pseudo header involving both the IP and transport protocol addresses.

Comment: @RonMaupin it truly is harder than I think. I tried finding libraries that deal with IP packets but they all rely on the system's sockets, therefore they do not do their own NAPT. Do you know about any library that does this?

Comment: No, I do not know a library. What I was trying to explain is that dealing with packets and routing is relatively easy, but you are now moving up the network stack into TCP segments and UDP datagrams, and that ends up being a completely different story. Each network layer has its own checksum (well IPv4 has a header checksum, but IPv6 does not, but IPv6 does not allow NAPT), TCP and UDP have a checksum covering the entire datagram, but it uses the IP address, too. If you change the IP address, you must change the checksums, or the packets will be rejected. NAPT is complicated.

Comment: Let me put it this way, Cisco (a giant network equipment vendor) declines to do NAPT on any device that does not have a hardware assist for it because NAPT is so complicated and resource intensive. Cisco puts that hardware in its routers, but not switches, so there is no NAPT for the switches. On the other hand, you can use something like iptables on a Linux host to do it, but it is in software, so it will slow packet forwarding and use a lot of system resources.

Comment: @RonMaupin I think I explained wrong. I only need the computer to answer TCP packet codes like SYN/ACK and to keep track of sequence numbers and maintain a buffer of packets so it has time to recover lost ones. Operating Systems already do this on software. I don't need routing or translation etc. However I can't find a library for something so simple (I presume)

Answer (score 0):

Following are technical answers considering that you know better your design goals and restrictions - you emphasize on simplisity .

1. std::**weak_ptr** may be used to break reference cycles formed by objects managed by std::shared_ptr.

[std::weak_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)

Since you are considering concurrency keep in mind following: predecessor that implements weak_ptr (Boost library) directly says that weak_ptr provides a very limited subset of operations since accessing its stored pointer is often dangerous in **multithreaded programs**. Your std implementation may inherit the same difficulties - please investigate or ask in separate question.

2. Internally, the elements in the unordered_map are organized into buckets depending on their hash values to allow for fast access to individual elements directly by their key values (with a **constant average time complexity** on average). Therefore usage of unordered_map is attractive from performance perspective.